# What does ご理解いただけた はずでは？ mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nuances, politeness, keigo

構いませんが すべては手紙に記した通りです... ご理解いただけた はずでは？

Answer (score 1):

> 構いませんが すべては手紙に記した通りです... ご理解いただけた はずでは？

It doesn't bother me but... everything is as written on the letter. You should have understood, shouldn't you?

> ご理解いただけたはずでは(ないでしょうか)？
>
> ご理解いただく。 : Have you/Get you to understand
>
> ご理解いただけた。 : I could get you to understand
>
> ご理解いただけたはずだ。 : I'm supposed to have been able to get you to understand
>
> ご理解いただけたはずでは(ないですか)。 : Am I not supposed to have been able to get you to understand?

Answer (score 1):

I think the implied continuation is 「ご理解いただけたはずではないのでしょうか？」

The rough equivalent in English would be "Not that I mind, but it's exactly as outlined in the letter. I believe you should have understood by now, is that not the case?"

Why does he speak in this tone? Who knows, not enough context. However, this is the tone that public workers speak with to customers. It can be used between friends when they are scolding each other.